# Change text colors every second

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

HTML Code

```js
function changeColor() {
  var x = document.getElementById("li1");
  x.style.color = "blue";
  if (x.style.color == "blue") {
    x.style.color = "yellow";
  }
}
window.setInterval("changeColor", 1000);
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="leftDiv">
    <div id="stepsId">
      <ol>
        <li id="li1"><b>Step 1</b></li>
        <li id="li2"><b>Step 2</b></li>
        <li id="li3"><b>Step 3</b></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My main goal is to cycle through the colors from steps 1 to 3 with each step turning blue > yellow > blue > yellow every second in ascending order. I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rn8ff2pj/) correct?

Comment: 1. add a closing bracket "}" to the changeColor function.  
2. remove the quotes in windows.setinterval: window.setInterval(changeColor,1000); 
3. make sure the javascript is loaded after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: `window.setInterval("changeColor", 1000);` needs to not have quotes around the function name...

Comment: *"each step ... in ascending order"* - Do you mean that when steps 1 and 3 are blue step 2 should be yellow, and vice versa? Or...? Your current code only tries to change the `li1` element.

Comment: by ascending order I meant, All steps appear Blue at first and upon running the code yellow starts cycling through steps 1,2,3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing JS doesn't work because you left the closing `}` off your function, and because in the call to `setInterval()` the function name in the first argument should not be in quotes (that is, pass a function reference, not a string).

But also, your code only references the first element in the list, and you said you want to change "each step...in ascending order". So maybe you could do something like the following, using `document.querySelectorAll("#stepsId li")` to select all of the li elements, then loop over them to change their colours in sequence:

```js
var colors = ["blue", "yellow"]
var currentColor = 0
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#stepsId li")

function changeColor() {
  --currentColor
  if (currentColor < 0) currentColor = colors.length -1
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].style.color = colors[(currentColor +i) % colors.length]
  }
}

setInterval(changeColor, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="stepsId">
  <ol>
    <li id="li1"><b>Step 1</b></li>
    <li id="li2"><b>Step 2</b></li>
    <li id="li3"><b>Step 3</b></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Note that you can add any number of colours into the array and it will cycle through all of them:

```js
var colors = ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green", "orange"]
var currentColor = 0
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#stepsId li")
function changeColor() {
  --currentColor
  if (currentColor < 0) currentColor = colors.length -1
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].style.color = colors[(currentColor +i) % colors.length]
  }
}
setInterval(changeColor, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="stepsId">
  <ol><li id="li1"><b>Step 1</b></li><li id="li2"><b>Step 2</b></li><li id="li3"><b>Step 3</b></li></ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1.Initialize color outside function
2.toggle color using setInterval

Codepen URL for reference- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NjWBxv

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementById("li1");
 x.style.color = "blue";

function changeColor(){
 x.style.color = x.style.color == "blue"?"yellow":"blue";
}

window.setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

There are few syntax errors like missing close '}' and remove quotes for function as it is not a string

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var x = setInterval(function() {

        console.log('rrr');
       var x = document.getElementById("li1");
            x.style.color = "blue";
            if (x.style.color == "blue"){
            x.style.color = "yellow";
            }
        }, 1000);

    </script>
    </script>
    <body>   
     <div class="leftDiv">
          <div id = "stepsId" > 
            <ol>
              <li id="li1"><b>Step 1</b></li>
              <li id="li2"><b>Step 2</b></li>
              <li id="li3"><b>Step 3</b></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the colors are not popping on the texts.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake

Comment: refer my 2nd answer

Comment: You can [edit] your existing answer, you don't have to post corrections in a separate answer. (Although it is acceptable to post two answers if they have different working solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
    <script>

        window.onload = function(){

        var x = document.getElementById("li1");
        x.style.color = "blue";

        function changeColor(){
            if (x.style.color == "blue"){
                x.style.color = "yellow";
            }
            else if (x.style.color == "yellow"){
                x.style.color = "blue";
            }
        };
        window.setInterval(changeColor,1000);



        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="leftDiv">
      <div id = "stepsId" > 
        <ol>
          <li id="li1"><b>Step 1</b></li>
          <li id="li2"><b>Step 2</b></li>
          <li id="li3"><b>Step 3</b></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only trying to change `li1`, rather than all of the `li` elements, which I assume is your intention. Try using `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.getElementById` and then iterating through the array, like so

```
function changeColor() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("#stepsId li");

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.color = x[i].style.color === 'blue' ? 'yellow' : 'blue';
   }
}
window.setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
```

This answer assumes that you want them all changing to the same color at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 1;
  var x = setInterval(function() {
   var x = document.getElementById("li1");
   console.log(x.style.color);
        if (x.style.color == "blue"){
          x.style.color = "yellow";
        } else if (x.style.color === "yellow"){
      x.style.color = "red";
    } else if (x.style.color === "red"){
      x.style.color = "blue";
    }

    }, 1000);

</script>
</script>
<body>   
 <div class="leftDiv">
      <div id = "stepsId" > 
        <ol>
          <li id="li1" style="color: blue;"><b>Step 1</b></li>
          <li id="li2"><b>Step 2</b></li>
          <li id="li3"><b>Step 3</b></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider first:

1. The JavaScript you posted is not syntactically valid because you fail to close your if statement curly brace (the "}").
2. The code inside your function will quickly. The only color change that you will see on the page is the final color value when your function finishes.

You will need to keep track of which element is yellow at any particular point and set up your function to determine which element should be turned yellow next.

```
var li1 = document.getElementById("li1");
var li2 = document.getElementById("li2");
var li3 = document.getElementById("li3");
var yellow = li1;

function changeColor() {
  if(li1 == yellow) {
    yellow = li2;
  } else if(li2 == yellow) {
    yellow = li3;
  } else {
    yellow = li1;
  }

  li1.style.color = "blue";
  li2.style.color = "blue";
  li3.style.color = "blue";
  yellow.style.color = "yellow";
}

window.setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve a cycle! But be careful while selecting lis, beacuse I just used **getElementsByTagName** which will give you all the li element

```js
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var i = 0
var color ='blue'
function changeColor(){
  if(i==3){
    i=0
  } 
  lis[i].style.color = color;
  if (lis[i].style.color == "blue"){
    color = 'yellow'
  }
  else{
    color = 'blue'
  }
  i = i+1;
}
window.setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

```html
<html>
<body>   
 <div class="leftDiv">
      <div id = "stepsId" > 
        <ol>
          <li id="li1"><b>Step 1</b></li>
          <li id="li2"><b>Step 2</b></li>
          <li id="li3"><b>Step 3</b></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```